# What is the safe way to do automated emails?

Tags: php, email, mail-server, mass-emails

I am in the middle of doing an auction site whereby emails are sent out regularly when people win items, sell items, didn't sell item, etc etc...

Which is the best way to send these emails so they don't get blocked or marked as spam ??

before with smaller sites I would have just sent them directly with the built in SMTP, but before on other sites these have eventually been blocked or marked as spam and then users end up not getting the emails at all..

Is there some sort of service i have to pay for to do safe HTML emails to customers of a site ?

Thanks

Lee

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to feel absolutely sure about it. However, there are general guidelines you should follow to minimize the chances your mail will end up in the Spam folder. I suggest that you check [this](http://wiki.apache.org/spamassassin/AvoidingFpsForSenders) out. Even though not every single mail service use SpamAssasin, the information is still useful.

Saved me a great deal of time. Hopefully, it will help you as well!

Answer (score 0):

use phpmailer class which will be helpful to send emails.you should send it manually or calling cron.